# Buscador simple con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero hacer un buscador simple con paginación, y que se muestre el resultado debajo del boton de buscar, lo máximo que he llegado es a mostrar el arreglo con la información de la base de datos, la pregunta es ¿Como muestro la información al pulsar el botón de busqueda, por ejemplo si quiero buscar solo  la columna noticiero_programa de la base de datos, para que se muestren los resultados debajo.

**1.-Vista**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')

    <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">buscar Noticiero</div>
            <form action="noticia/buscar" method="get" onsubmit="return showLoad()">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label class="label-control">Nombre del noticiero</label>
                <input type="text" name="noticiero_turno" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar nombre del noticiero/descripcion" required="required">
                <br>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">buscar</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- check if $buscar variable is set, display buscar result -->
    @if (isset($buscar))
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">Resultado de la busqueda</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class='table-responsive'>
                  <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>PROGRAMA</th>
                        <th>TURNO</th>
                        <th>FECHA</th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    @foreach($buscar as $buscars)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$buscars->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$buscars['noticiero_programa']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$buscars['noticiero_turno']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$buscars['noticiero_fecha']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <center>{{ $buscar->appends(Request::only('noticiero_turno','noticiero_programa'))->links() }}</center>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="{{url('noticia/buscar')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Restaurar busqueda</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif

    @stop
```

**2.-Controlador**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function busqueda(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    if($request->get('busqueda')){
        $noticias = Noticia::where("noticiero_turno", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('busqueda')}%")
            ->paginate(5);
    }else{
  $noticias = Noticia::paginate(5);
    }

    return response($noticias);
}
```

**3.-Rutas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 Route::get('noticia/buscar', 'NoticiaController@busqueda');
```

Arreglo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**4.-Base de datos tabla noticias**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás enviando la variable `$buscar` a la vista por eso no se nuestran los resultados.

```
public function busqueda(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    if($request->get('busqueda')){
        $noticias = Noticia::where("noticiero_turno", "LIKE", "%{$request->get('busqueda')}%")
            ->paginate(5);
      return view('NOMBRE_VISTA')->with('buscar', $noticias);
    }
    //else{
    //  $noticias = Noticia::paginate(5);
    //}

    // return response($noticias);
    return view('NOMBRE_VISTA');
}
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, Saludos